# Getting a Bayesian NN to learn the noise within training data and thereby calculating prediction uncertainties

Tags: tensorflow, bayesian, confidence-interval, tensorflow-probability, bayesian-deep-learning

I am trying to train a bayesian NN for noisy time series prediction. I have problems in

1. getting the model to learn the linear releationship in the data
2. getting the model to learn the increasing noise
   The goal is that the model learns the noise and therefor is able to calculate an uncertainty within interference after learning.
   Data:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
lookBack = 128
inputDim = 1
lookAHead = 32
split = 0.15
# create data
data_length = 10000
y_data = []
for ii in range(data_length):
    y_data.append(0.5*ii + 2 + np.random.normal(0, ii*ii/100000))
x_data = np.arange(data_length)

#normalize data
y_data = np.array(y_data)
y_data = (y_data - np.mean(y_data)) / np.std(y_data)

plt.plot(x_data, y_data)
plt.show()

#construct input/target data
train_data_input = []
train_data_target = []
for ii in range(shape[0] - lookBack - lookAHead):
    train_data_input.append(np.array(y_data[ii:ii+lookBack]))
    train_data_target.append(y_data[ii+lookBack + lookAHead])

train_data_input = np.array(train_data_input)
train_data_input = np.expand_dims(train_data_input, axis = -1)

train_data_target = np.array(train_data_target)
```

My Model:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input

inputModel = Input(shape=(lookBack, inputDim))
features = keras.layers.Flatten()(inputModel)
features = layers.Dense(32, activation = "tanh")(features)
features = tfp.layers.DenseVariational(
            units=8,
            make_prior_fn=prior,
            make_posterior_fn=posterior,
            kl_weight=1/(train_data_input.shape[0]*(1-split)),
            activation="tanh",
            )(features)
```

I tried different output types, just a regression value or a distribution that is learnt:

```py
if output_type == "val":
    outputs = layers.Dense(1)(features)

if output_type == "dist":
    distribution_params = Dense(2) (features)
    #c = np.log(np.expm1(1.0))
    #outputs = tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=t[..., :1],
    #                       scale=1e-3 + tf.math.softplus(c+0.05 * t[..., 1:])))(distribution_params)
    outputs = tfp.layers.IndependentNormal(1)(distribution_params)


model = keras.Model(inputs=inputModel, outputs=outputs)

def negative_loglikelihood(targets, estimated_distribution):
    return -estimated_distribution.log_prob(targets)

loss = None
if output_type == "dist"
    loss = negative_loglikelihood 
    #def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    #    return tf.keras.losses.KLD(y_true, y_pred)
if output_type == "val":
    loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loss=loss
    )

model.fit(x = train_data_input, y = train_data_target, epochs=25, validation_split=split)
```

I tried different unit sizes, loss functions (-log_pob, KLD) activation functions, (learnable) priors (1/2, see below), and posteriors (1/2, see below) but my model doesn´t really learn useful stuff. Furthermore I would expect the stdDev of my output to increase with increasing x as the noise is increasing too which is not the case.

```py
def prior1(kernel_size, bias_size, dtype=None):
        n = kernel_size + bias_size
        prior_model = keras.Sequential(
            [
                tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
                    lambda t: tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(
                        loc=tf.zeros(n), scale_diag=tf.ones(n).
                    )
                )
            ]
        )
        return prior_model
    
    def prior2(kernel_size, bias_size, dtype=None):
        n = kernel_size + bias_size
        c = np.log(np.expm1(1.0))
        return tf.keras.Sequential([
            tfp.layers.VariableLayer(2*n, dtype=dtype),
            tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfp.distributions.Independent(
                tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=t[...,:n], scale=1e-3 + tf.math.softplus(c + 0.05 * t[..., n:])), reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1))
        ])

def posterior1(kernel_size, bias_size, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    posterior_model = keras.Sequential(
        [
           tfp.layers.VariableLayer(
                tfp.layers.MultivariateNormalTriL.params_size(n), dtype=dtype
            ),
            tfp.layers.MultivariateNormalTriL(n),
        ]
    )
    return posterior_model
    
def posterior2(kernel_size, bias_size=0, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    c = np.log(np.expm1(1.0))
        
    return keras.Sequential([
        tfp.layers.VariableLayer(2 * n, dtype=dtype),
        tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfp.distributions.Independent(
            tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=t[..., :n], 
                       scale=1e-5 + tf.nn.softplus(c + t[..., n:])),
            )),
    ])
```

Evaluation of the model:

```py
predictions = []
means = []
stds = []
for ii in range(20):
    prediction = model(train_data_input)
    if output_type == "val":
        predictions.append(prediction)
    if output_type == "dist":
        means.append(prediction.mean())
        stds.append(prediction.stddev())
        
if output_type == "val":
    predictions = np.array(predictions)
    predicted_mean = np.mean(predictions, axis = 0)
    predicted_std = np.std(predictions, axis = 0)
        
if output_type == "dist":
    predicted_mean = np.mean(np.array(means), axis = 0)
    predicted_std = np.mean(np.array(stds), axis = 0)
    
lower_bound = predicted_mean - predicted_std
upper_bound = predicted_mean + predicted_std

plt.plot(x_data, y_data)
#Plot the mean
plt.plot(np.arange(predicted_mean.shape[0]) + lookBack + lookAHead, np.squeeze(predicted_mean), color = "r")
#Plot the begging of the test set
plt.vlines(x=float(1-split)*predicted_mean.shape[0] + lookBack + lookAHead,ymin = np.min(predicted_mean), ymax = np.max(predicted_mean), colors = "g")
#Plot the hopefully increasing stdDev
plt.plot(np.arange(predicted_mean.shape[0]) + lookBack + lookAHead, predicted_std, color = "g")
#Plot mean +/- stdDev
plt.plot(np.arange(predicted_mean.shape[0]) + lookBack + lookAHead, np.squeeze(lower_bound), color = "r", alpha = 0.5)
plt.plot(np.arange(predicted_mean.shape[0]) + lookBack + lookAHead, np.squeeze(upper_bound), color = "r", alpha = 0.5)
```

Im thankful for any advice on how to get the models learning.

Answer (score 0):

In the code below, a random input signal (`y_rv`) is generated from a known mean and std at each time point (`y_mean` and `y_std`). The model takes in a window from the input signal, and it learns to predict the mean and std that were used to sample that signal (i.e. input is `y_rv`, and targets are `y_mean` and `y_std`).

I started by simplifying model down to a single-output regression model predicting the mean. ReLU activation helped stabilise training. Once that basic model was working, I added in a second output for the standard deviation.

I modified the model and targets so that the model predicts a sequence of values up to and including 32 points into the future, rather than simply predicting a single vector at t=32. I think this gives the model more context when predicting standard deviation, rather than having to rely on a single data point. Adding dropout also helped the model stabilise predictions of standard deviation. Directly estimating the std worked better than estimating `log(std)`.

Showing a single window from the training set:

[image]

Target and predictions:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

random.seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)

lookBack = 128
lookAHead = 32
split = 0.15

# create data
data_length = 10_000
y_mean = np.empty(data_length)
y_std = np.empty_like(y_mean)
y_rv = np.empty_like(y_mean)
for ii in range(data_length):
    mean = 0.5*ii + 2
    std = ii**2 / 100_000
    
    y_mean[ii] = mean
    y_std[ii] = std
    #Sample an rv from the Normal(mean, std) distribution
    y_rv[ii] = np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=std)

#construct input/target data
train_input = []
train_target_mean = []
train_target_std = []
train_target_rv = []

for ii in range(data_length - lookBack - lookAHead):
    #For ii, train will use a lookBack-sized window starting at ii
    train_input.append(np.array(y_rv[ii:ii + lookBack]))
    
    #Use it to predict the value(s) that's lookAHead beyond the window end
    target_start = ii + lookBack
    target_end = target_start + lookAHead
    train_target_mean.append( np.array(y_mean[target_start:target_end]) )
    train_target_std.append( np.array(y_std[target_start:target_end]) )
    train_target_rv.append( np.array(y_rv[target_start:target_end]) )

train_input = np.array(train_input)
train_target_mean = np.array(train_target_mean)
train_target_std = np.array(train_target_std)
train_target_rv = np.array(train_target_rv)

train_input_scaled = (train_input - train_input.mean(axis=0)) / train_input.std(axis=0)

train_target_mean_std = np.stack(
    [train_target_mean, train_target_std],
    axis=2
)

#
#View a window of data
#
#Select window to plot
window_start = 500
window_end = window_start + lookBack

window_range = list(range(window_start, window_end))
window_range_target = list(range(window_start, window_end + lookAHead))

#Training data over window i
plt.plot(window_range, train_input[window_start, :],
         color='tab:green', label=f'train_input[window #{window_start}] (y_rv)', zorder=3)
#Target over window i + lookAHead
plt.plot(window_range_target,
         y_mean[window_start:window_end + lookAHead],
         color='tab:red', linestyle=':',
         label=f'y_mean[{window_start}:{window_start}+{lookBack}+{lookAHead}]')
plt.xlabel('index')
plt.ylabel('y')

#y std
plt.plot(window_range_target,
         y_mean[window_start:window_end + lookAHead] +\
         2 * y_std[window_start:window_end + lookAHead],
         color='tab:purple', linewidth=3, label='±2*y_std')
plt.plot(window_range_target,
         y_mean[window_start:window_end + lookAHead] -\
         2 * y_std[window_start:window_end + lookAHead],
         color='tab:purple', linewidth=3)
plt.ylabel('y')

plt.axvline(x=window_end, linestyle=':', linewidth=1, color='k', label='window ends')

plt.gcf().set_size_inches(7, 2.5)
plt.gcf().legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.7, 1.1))
plt.margins(x=0)
plt.show()

#
#Model
#
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

#Define model
tf.random.set_seed(0)
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

inputModel = layers.Input(shape=lookBack)
features = layers.Flatten()(inputModel)
features = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(features)
features = layers.Dropout(rate=0.2)(features)
features = layers.Dense(32, activation="relu")(features)
outputs = [layers.Dense(lookAHead, name='mean_out')(features),
           layers.Dense(lookAHead, name='std_out')(features)
           ]

#Compile model
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputModel, outputs=outputs)
loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss, loss_weights=[0.5, 0.5])

#Fit model
model.fit(x=train_input_scaled, y=[train_target_mean, train_target_std],
          epochs=20, batch_size=32, validation_split=split)

#
# Plot input, targets, and predictions
#
#Get predictions
pred_mean, pred_std = [t.numpy() for t in model(train_input_scaled)]

#Plot
x_pred = list(range(lookBack, data_length - lookAHead))
plt.plot(x_pred, y_rv[x_pred], c='tab:brown', lw=2, alpha=0.4, label='input features')

plt.plot(x_pred, y_mean[x_pred], c='black', lw=5, label='target mean')
plt.plot(x_pred, y_mean[x_pred] + 2 * y_std[x_pred], c='black', lw=4, ls=':', label='target std')
plt.plot(x_pred, y_mean[x_pred] - 2 * y_std[x_pred], c='black', lw=4, ls=':')

plt.plot(x_pred, pred_mean[:, -1], c='tab:cyan', lw=0.3, label='predicted mean')

plt.plot(x_pred, pred_mean[:, -1] + 2 * pred_std[:, -1],
         c='tab:cyan', lw=0.5, label='predicted std')
plt.plot(x_pred, pred_mean[:, -1] - 2 * pred_std[:, -1],
         c='tab:cyan', lw=0.5)

plt.axvline(x=(1 - split) * len(train_input_scaled),
            c='black', lw=1, ls=':', label='train-val split')
plt.xlabel('index')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Input, targets, and predictions')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5, 3)
plt.gcf().legend(ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=(0.9, 1.25))
plt.show()
```

This network only looks at the input features when making its prediction and doesn't use its previous predictions. Allowing the network to access its previous predictions would make it a recurrent net, which is the usual choice for time series.

`GaussianProcessRegressor` in `sklearn` directly models the mean and std of a time series, and could provide a good baseline measure if you wanted to compare your NN against other techniques.

---

Estimating mean and sd from the noisy signal (could be used for creating a training set):

[image]

```
t_axis = np.arange(data_length).reshape(-1, 1)
plt.plot(t_axis, y_rv, linestyle='none', marker='.', alpha=0.8, label='noisy data')

plt.plot(y_mean, c='k', label='ground truth μ±2σ', lw=10, alpha=0.3)
plt.plot(y_mean - 2 * y_std, c='k', lw=10, alpha=0.3)
plt.plot(y_mean + 2 * y_std, c='k', lw=10, alpha=0.3)

#GPR estimate of mean/std
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process import kernels

kernel = kernels.DotProduct() + 0.1 * kernels.DotProduct()**2 * kernels.WhiteKernel()
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(
    kernel=kernel, random_state=np.random.RandomState(0)
)
gpr.fit(t_axis, y_rv)

gpr_mean, gpr_sd = gpr.predict(t_axis, return_std=True)
plt.plot(t_axis, gpr_mean, c='tab:orange', lw=4, label='gaussian process')
plt.plot(t_axis, gpr_mean - 2 * gpr_sd, lw=4, c='tab:orange')
plt.plot(t_axis, gpr_mean + 2 * gpr_sd, lw=4, c='tab:orange')

#Rolling window estimate of mean/std
window_size = 30
df = pd.DataFrame(y_rv, columns=['Values'])
rolling_mean = df.Values.rolling(window=window_size, min_periods=1).mean()
rolling_sd = df.Values.rolling(window=window_size, min_periods=1).std()
rolling_sd.iloc[0] = rolling_sd.iloc[1]

plt.plot(rolling_mean, c='tab:red', lw=2, label='rolling window')
plt.plot(rolling_mean - 2 * rolling_sd, c='tab:red', lw=2)
plt.plot(rolling_mean + 2 * rolling_sd, c='tab:red', lw=2)

plt.suptitle('Estimating μ and σ from noisy data')
plt.title('Gaussian process vs. rolling window', fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel('sample index')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.xlim(400, 1000); plt.ylim(300, 1200)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5, 3.5)
plt.show()
```

---

Implementation using `torch.distributions` to learn the distribution.

[image]

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

random.seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)

look_back = 128
look_ahead = 32
split = 0.15

#
# Create data
#
data_length = 10_000
y_mean = np.empty(data_length)
y_sd = np.empty_like(y_mean)
y_rv = np.empty_like(y_mean)
for ii in range(data_length):
    mean = ii + 2
    sd = ii**2 / (data_length * 10)
    
    y_mean[ii] = mean
    y_sd[ii] = sd
    
    #Sample an rv from the Normal(mean, std) distribution
    #This will be the noisy input to the model
    y_rv[ii] = np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=sd)

#
# Construct input/target data
#
train_input = []
train_target_rv = []

for ii in range(data_length - look_back - look_ahead):
    #For ii, train will use a lookBack-sized window starting at ii
    train_input.append(np.array(y_rv[ii:ii + look_back]))
    
    #Use it to predict the value(s) that's lookAHead beyond the window end
    train_target_rv.append(y_rv[ii + look_back + look_ahead])

train_input = np.array(train_input)
train_target_rv = np.array(train_target_rv).reshape(-1, 1)

#
#View a window of data
#
#Select window to plot
window_num = 9000
window_end = window_num + look_back

window_range = list(range(window_num, window_end))
window_range_target = list(range(window_num, window_end + look_ahead))

#Training data over window i
plt.plot(window_range, train_input[window_num, :],
         color='tab:green', label=f'input data window #{window_num}', zorder=3)

# over window i + lookAHead
plt.plot(window_range_target, y_mean[window_num:window_end + look_ahead],
         color='tab:purple', linestyle='--', linewidth=3,
         label=f'$\mu$[{window_num}:{window_num}+{look_back}+{look_ahead}]')
plt.xlabel('index')
plt.ylabel('y')

#y std
plt.plot(window_range_target,
         y_mean[window_num:window_end + look_ahead] +\
         2 * y_sd[window_num:window_end + look_ahead],
         color='tab:purple', linewidth=3, label='±2$\sigma$')
plt.plot(window_range_target,
         y_mean[window_num:window_end + look_ahead] -\
         2 * y_sd[window_num:window_end + look_ahead],
         color='tab:purple', linewidth=3)
plt.ylabel('y')

plt.axvline(x=window_end - 1, color='k', label=f'look_back={look_back} window ends')

plt.gcf().set_size_inches(7, 2.5)
plt.gcf().legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.8, 1.2), ncol=2, fontsize=10)
plt.margins(x=0)
plt.show()

#
#Model
#
import torch
from torch import nn, optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        intermediate_dim = look_back // 2
        self.feed_fwd = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(look_back, intermediate_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(intermediate_dim),

            nn.Linear(intermediate_dim, intermediate_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(intermediate_dim)
        )
        
        self.mean_encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(intermediate_dim, intermediate_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(intermediate_dim, 1),
        )
        
        self.std_encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(intermediate_dim, intermediate_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(intermediate_dim, 1),
            nn.Softplus()
        )
            
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.feed_fwd(x)
        mu = self.mean_encoder(x)
        sigma = self.std_encoder(x)
        return torch.distributions.Normal(mu, sigma)

torch.manual_seed(0)
encoder = Encoder()
optimizer = optim.NAdam(encoder.parameters())

n_epochs = 150
batch_size = 32

X_t = torch.tensor(train_input).float()
y_t = torch.tensor(train_target_rv).float()
Xy_paired = list(zip(X_t, y_t))
dataloader = DataLoader(Xy_paired, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

losses = []
encoder.train()
for epoch in range(n_epochs):

    running_loss = 0
    for batch_num, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
                
        predicted_dist = encoder(X)
        nll_loss = -predicted_dist.log_prob(y).mean(dim=0)
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()            
        nll_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    
        running_loss += nll_loss.item()
    if not (epoch % 10): print(epoch, '{:.0f}'.format( running_loss / len(dataloader)))
    losses.append(running_loss / len(dataloader))

plt.plot(losses)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5, 3)
plt.show()

#Get predictions
encoder.eval()

with torch.no_grad():
    prediction = encoder(X_t)
    pred_mean = prediction.mean.numpy()
    pred_sd = prediction.stddev.numpy()
    sample_from_prediction = prediction.sample()

#Plot
x_pred = list(range(look_back, data_length - look_ahead))
plt.plot(x_pred, y_rv[x_pred], c='tab:brown', lw=2, alpha=0.4, label='input data')

plt.plot(x_pred, y_mean[x_pred], c='black', lw=5, label='actual $\mu$')
plt.plot(x_pred, y_mean[x_pred] + 2 * y_sd[x_pred], c='black', lw=4, ls=':', label='actual 2$\sigma$')
plt.plot(x_pred, y_mean[x_pred] - 2 * y_sd[x_pred], c='black', lw=4, ls=':')

# plt.plot(x_pred, sample_from_prediction, c='tab:cyan', lw=0.3, label='sample rv from prediction')
plt.plot(x_pred, pred_mean, c='tab:cyan', lw=0.3, label='predicted $\mu$')

plt.plot(x_pred, pred_mean + 2 * pred_sd, c='tab:red', lw=0.5, label='predicted 2$\sigma$')
plt.plot(x_pred, pred_mean - 2 * pred_sd, c='tab:red', lw=0.5)

plt.xlabel('index')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Input, ground truth, and predictions')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5, 3)
plt.gcf().legend(ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=(0.9, 1.25))

# plt.xlim(6_000, 10_000); plt.ylim(4_000, 12_000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I am able to understand and reproduce your results. However, I´m bothering with the fact that the model is explicitly given the target std_dev `train_target_std` during training. In my experiments this is not given and should be learned from the data. As far as I grasped the concept of bayesian NN it should be learnable. Alternatively training on a target output distribution `outputs = tfp.layers.IndependentNormal(1)(distribution_params)` should be able to learn the std_dev without explicelty given the target std_dev like in your example.

Comment: To summarize: You train a "double regressor" on the mean and the std deviation but I want to learn the std deviation without having knowledge about it at training time.

Comment: I further experimented with training on a [lookAHead] sequence instead of a point prediction as targets. Unfortunately without much success.

Comment: I see. I've tried another model that attempts to learn the distribution, but haven't been able to get it to work. My model takes in the 128 features and projects them down to a mean vector (size 32) and an std vector (size 32). The model samples that mean-std distribution, and is trained to minimize the MSE between that sample and the target. The model should learn the appropriate mean and std for 32 points into the future. The model fails to learn the std though.

Comment: Unfortunately, that´s exactly my problem.

Comment: Suppose the model predicts the mean and std for some timepoint. You need a way of penalising the model when its estimated mean/std is bad. I think this ultimately means you'll need a reference mean/std to serve as a standard by which the model corrects itself. I supplied the model with the ground truth mean and std. If the ground truth mean/std is not available for training, then you could instead compute an approximate mean/std of the target, and get the model to predict that. In this case, the input will be your *noisy* signal & the target will be the approximate target mean/std. Thoughts?

Comment: In terms of  how you could derive a mean/std from the noisy signal...A simple approach would be to compute a rolling-window estimate of the mean/std over the noisy signal, giving you an estimated mean/std for each point. Another approach is to model the mean/std trends using a gaussian process. In both cases you'll end up with a training set that pairs the noisy signal at point *t* with an estimated mean/std for point *t*. You can then train a neural net to map a window of the noisy data at *t* to the predicted mean/std at *t+32*.

Comment: I guess this means that you have to somehow model and learn the std deviation explicitly. However I thought this is exactly what either bayesian NN or distribution outputs are designed for.

Comment: My implementation was 'from scratch', so I needed to compute the std explicitly. My presumption is that the Bayesian layers you used don't need std to be explicitly provided, but behind the scenes they make their own assessment of how close they are to matching the input distribution.

Comment: But I am not able to make it work and I don´t know why. That´s exactly my question.

Comment: I've updated the end of my answer to show how I got a model somewhat working using `torch.distributions`.